# Multiple Rails App Same DB? Other options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, api

Hi I am looking to build a set of solo apps. But I am finding they are sharing a common main table. For example let the table be food. All of these apps would use the food table but have zero other tables in common. I have been thinking of the best way to approach this problem. Either using a shared db among all the apps or an API for just that table. I have been reading that using a shared db is a horrible idea and an API would mean that each app would probably have to have the food table in it and just pull updatea from the API every now and then(This is cause of how the food table would be used with sorting and pulling info in. Seems crazy to possibly be making an API call every page load and process that data over and over). Sorry for ranting on but was hoping someone would have an idea of rails best practices on this one

Comment: What exactly do these applications share?

Comment: They share that they all revolve around a constantly updating table of food. Say one app uses the table to help you make dinner. Another would be a calorie counter and daily tracking with charts. They both need to know about the food table but every other table in the apps would be different

Comment: Hahaha sorry, I was thinking food was an example table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're inclined on mapping information for both applications I suggest just merging the applications into one.

If you must couple them, then they should be two parts of a greater system.

If you do not want to create this kind of coupling, then the API approach is required.

One application might just depend on another for acquiring records.

But there is the question of, if they are both separate applications, then why should they "depend" on each others data.

Much easy to separate them at every level or namespace application parts of a larger system.

Perhaps even a 3rd application as a standalone API for both would be clever.

That said, you can create a smart application that can create records and await further data to be used.

```
Example: 
Recipe app APIs to Calorie app new foods with unknown calories
Calorie app doesn't respond with that record until calorie amount is set
Calorie app understands nested foods and can sum a total for the parent food
Calorie app creates parent food with calories set
From now on API towards Calorie app for that Recipe's calories will return the recipe's food record
As more foods with calories are created the calories become more precise
```